# TortoiseGit does not show commit log properly

Tags: git, bitbucket, tortoisegit

I am using TortoiseGit with a repository on Bitbucket. The problem is that when I make "show log" in TortoiseGit and even refresh the log I still don't see all the pushed commits in the repository. If I go to Bitbucket web page I can see them in the list of commits but they are not shown in the TortoiseGit log until I make a pull. Is there a way to see in TortoiseGit Log all the commits before making a pull ?

Comment: Can you confirm that you are looking at the same branch locally and on Bitbucket?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Bitbucket web page runs in the server using the Git repositories located in the server so you're always looking to updated data. Your TortoiseGit runs locally using your local repositories, so you need to update the repository to see updated data. You can update your repository executing either a fetch or a pull. See more details about fetch and pull [here](https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-dug-pull.html).

Answer (score 1):

Check the `All Branches` checkbox (bottom-left corner) of Log Message dialog, see:

[image]